# Real time update data for 3d graph Plotly

Tags: plotly

I need to update 3d plot in real time on Plotly

Data is received in an endless loop. But the code below does not update the graph automatically, but only after a manual update

Something like this

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=1000,
            n_intervals=0
        ),
    ]
)

X, Y, Z = [1], [2], [3]
a = iter(MyIterator())

@app.callback(
    Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')]
)
def update_graph_scatter(n):
    XYZ = next(a)

    X.append(XYZ[0])
    Y.append(XYZ[1])
    Z.append(XYZ[2])

    DATA = go.Scatter3d(x=X, y=Y, z=Z, mode='lines')

    return {'data': [DATA],
            'layout': go.Layout()}

app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: When should your program stop? it will run forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify in the `dcc.Interval` what is the maximum number of points you will receive.

**Code**

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import numpy as np


app = Dash(__name__)

X,Y,Z= [],[],[]

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph'),
       dcc.Interval(
                            id='interval-component',
                            interval=1000, # in milliseconds
                            n_intervals = 1, # start
                            max_intervals = 100, #end , You should specify how many points you will receive
                        ),
    ]
)



@app.callback(
    Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')]
)
def update_graph_scatter(n):
    X.append(np.random.rand()*10)
    Y.append(np.random.rand()*10)
    Z.append(np.random.rand()*10)
    
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_scatter3d(x=X, y=Y, z=Z, mode='markers')

    return fig

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Output**

[image]