# live data Dash plot with python

Tags: python-3.x, plot, plotly-dash

i have write a code in python to plot data in realtime. there is only one problem the code run i get no errors but there is also no plot in web page that i created.
can any one help me pleadse?
thanks

ma code

```
#app work 
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#html layout 
app.layout = html.Div(
    [    
        dcc.Graph(id = 'live-graph',
                  animate = True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id = 'graph-update',
            interval = 1*1000,
            n_intervals = 0 ),])
```

Comment: Try to remove `animate = True`

Comment: it did not work, i still get the same screen

Comment: Did you make sure there are data to plot from the database?

Comment: the data are saved in database once per sec thats i am sure.

Comment: Since you read your data from database, could you please try to add a dummy data to your question to be able to replicate your problem in my machine and help you?

Comment: 2022-10-17 09:59:28 4.48045366769477
2022-10-17 09:59:27 4.50315409936358
2022-10-17 09:59:26 4.45826464393909
2022-10-17 09:59:25 4.50326913634171
2022-10-17 09:59:24 4.5003598332834
2022-10-17 09:59:23 4.49691945277684
2022-10-17 09:59:22 4.5009838939886

Comment: that is the last data from my database i hope you ment that ; thanks

Comment: I meant to add your data to the question please not in the comments. Also, please format it into dataframe or dictionary.

Comment: I also encourage you to see this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/74067695/16733101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend checking the data in raw[0] and raw[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdHaL.gif) and I do not think you need `list(str())`. You need also to bring the data from the database by increasing the value after `LIMIT`. Therefore, you should let the size of the data coming from the database increase dynamically and being controlled by `n_intervals` such that `select * from ..... LIMIT` + n and absolutely the value of n should start from 1, therefore set `n_intervals` to 1 accordingly. Another error in your program, you return figure which is not graph_object and dbc.Graph expects graph_object.

In the example below, I created a dataframe from CSV file, but you can understand the logic and apply it directly to your example:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import numpy 


app = Dash(__name__)
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph'),
       dcc.Interval(
                            id='interval-component',
                            interval=1000, # in milliseconds
                            n_intervals = 1, # start
                        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')]
)

def update_graph_scatter(n):
    
    if n <= len(df):
        row = df.iloc[:n,:]
        w =  numpy.asarray(row[df.columns[0]])
        volt = numpy.asarray(row[df.columns[1]])

        data = go.Scatter( x = w , y = volt , hoverinfo='text+name+y', name='Scatter', mode= 'lines+markers', )
        layout = go.Layout(xaxis = dict(range=[min(w),max(w)]), yaxis = dict(range=[min(volt)-1,max(volt)+1]))
        figure = go.Figure({'data' :data, 'layout' : layout})
        return figure


app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

[image]